# Server.MapPath() not working outside controller ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My service function:

```
public void Create(PostAddRequest model)
        {
            var featuredImageFile = "/Content/img/uploads/" + Guid.NewGuid() + "_" + model.FeaturedImage.FileName;
            var post = new Post()
            {
                Title = model.Title,
                CategoryId = model.CategoryId,
                Content = model.Content,
                Description = model.Description,
                PersonId = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId(),
                FeaturedImagePath = featuredImageFile,
                CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow
            };
            model.FeaturedImage.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(featuredImageFile));
            _unitOfWork.PostRepository.AddPost(post);
            _unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
        }
```

I'm getting an error saying: `The name 'Server' does not exist in the current context`.
This error doesn't occur when I use Server.MapPath in a controller, but I'm using a 3 layer architecture and need to use it on a function outside a controller.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `HttpContext`
`HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath()`
How to use in class library:
`Right click on References` -> `Add reference` -> Select `Assemblies` section in the left side -> Search for `System.Web` -> Select it -> Click Ok -> Done

Comment: .....I've been trying find a solution for the past two hours, only to realize my `Content` folder is in `Presentation Layer` and my services are in "BLL". Any idea how to target the other project?

Comment: Right click on References -> Add reference -> Select Assemblies section in left side -> Search for `System.Web' -> Select it -> Click Ok -> Done.